# Почему шрифт на внешнем мониторе зернистый?

Tags: macos, mac, apple, железо, монитор

Всем привет

У меня macbook pro 2015, подключаю монитор Phillips 222e. Подключаю по HDMI+переходник DVI( в мониторе нет родного HDMI).

Так вот, картинка на внешнем мониторе есть, но шрифты не очень читабельны. Они как будто зернистые, расплывчатые, прозрачные. Очень трудно подобрать слово.

Вот скриншот, проблему видно особенно на вкладке со стаком: http://joxi.ru/krDq38Bh56Llmp

Пробовал менять разрешние, ставить патч forced RGB,  менял кабели, танцевал с бубном, взывал к Стиву, ничего не помогло

Надеюсь на вас

Спасибо

Comment: возможно, выставлено не родное разрешение. Хотя шрифты обычные, маковские, после которых текут глаза.

Comment: @KoVadim, нет, разрешение родное

Comment: А возможно, Вы просто привыкли к ретине...

Comment: @KoVadim на работе Виндовс, 2 монитора, шрифты в порядке

Comment: там мак, там виндовс. Не находите, что это разные случаи?

Comment: @KoVadim, давайте, если не знаете, то не будете писать ересь?

Comment: google://macbook pro 2015 second display blurry fonts, http://www.mathewinkson.com/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor проверяли? там хоть и 2013, но способ работы макоси с мониторами хз - мог и не измениться - там дальше (These steps have been updated for Mac OS version 10.11, “El Capitan”) - точно не изменился

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов у вас ретина и мак ожидает монитора с высоким разрешением (желательно родной), под чужие мониторы Apple не адаптирует вывод. Я за 2 года тоже так и не решил проблему, старая прошка отлично выводит (тоже, конечно, не на любом мониторе), ретина - дает вырвиглазную картинку на обычном мониторе.

Comment: @strangeqargo Да, пробовал, не помогло. Этот фикс, помоему, работает с miniDispaly, помоему

Comment: @cheops очень жаль. Спасибо за ответ